# Integrability of any function

Tags: calculus, integration

> What is the condition for a function to be Integrable?

I'm a beginner. I know that every function is not differentiable but I don't know the condition for integrability. So if someone gives time for writing an answer for this question then it will be very very helpful for me to step forward in my mathematics career. Thank You!!!

Comment: There are different notions of integrability. I would suggest, you read for example [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral) first and then come back with some more concrete questions.

Answer (score 1):

For a function to be integrable it must be continuous on that interval. Note here that if all continuous functions are integrable but not all integrable functions are continuous. 
Example :
 $$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{rl}3 & 0\leq x<1\\ 5 & 1\leq x\leq 2.\end{array}\right.$$

This $f$ is clearly not continuous at 1, but it is Riemann integrable on $[0,2]$, with $\int_0^2 f(x)\ dx = 8$.

Comment: Do you mean continuous almost everywhere on that interval? Since your example contradicts what you say in the first sentence.

Comment: The example I gave is to prove that not all integrable functions are continuous. Although a function is integrable only when it's continuous on the interval we are integrating it on. @LiChunMin

Comment: We are integrating $f$ on $[0,2]$ and $f$ is not continuous on $[0,2]$, isn't it? So do you mean "for a function to be integrable on an interval, it must be continuous everywhere on that interval" instead?

Comment: "For a function to be integrable it must be continuous on that interval" this is exactly what I wrote in first line, btw you know Riemann integration? @LiChunMin

Comment: I mean "almost everywhere". Yes I am learning analysis.

Comment: Yes exactly @LiChunMin

Comment: You told only one point of function to be integrable. But how to determine whether a function is integrable or not if it is discontinuous?

Comment: I'll recommend you knowing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral Riemann integral first then maybe you can place your question well as for what you lack understanding.

Answer (score 1):

For Riemann integral, we have the Lebesgue criterion in the sense that:

For a bounded real function $f:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow\Bbb{R},$ $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ if and only if the set $\{x\in[a,b]|f$ is not continuous at $x\}$ is of measure zero with the Lebesgue measure.

You can consult more text on integration to taste it.

Comment: You just copied first line of the rieman integral from Wikipedia

Comment: Indeed I didn't see that before I typed.

Comment: I read it, and I don't think if our internet linked to the same Wikipedia.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry actually I read it an hour before I sent the comment and I messed up everything. Sorry!!!